# Differential of strict function

Tags: derivatives

Let $e^{f(x) } $=lnx.if g)(x)  is the inverse of f(x) , the n derivative of g(x)  is

I first found the inverse of the function which is $e^{e^x}$ and then substituted it on the formulae
$$(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$ but the answer I am getting is not matching. I got x$e^{e^x}$ which is not correct. How to do this

Comment: You found $g(x)=e^{e^x}$, so you do not need to use the inverse derivative formula. Just use the chain rule to find $g'(x)$..

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{f(x)}=\ln x$$
$$f(x)=\ln(\ln x)$$
$$y=\ln(\ln x)$$

swap $x$ and $y$
$$x=\ln(\ln y)$$

thus $$f^{-1}(x)=\ln(\ln x)$$

$$g(x)=\ln(\ln x)$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x \cdot x}$$